# What is the distribution?

Tags: probability, moment-generating-functions

Let $X_1,X_2,...,X_n$ be i.i.d with Bernoulli distribution (so the p.m.f is  $\theta^{x}(1-\theta)^{1-x})$.

I want to find the distribution of $\bar X$.

I calculated the moment generating function of $\bar X$ (by calculating $E[e^{\frac t n (X_1+...+X_n)}]$, and I found the M.G.F of $\bar X$ as $(1-\theta+\theta e^{\frac t n})^n.$ But I don't know the distribution. Is it $\text{Binom}(n,\theta)$, or $\text{Binom} (1,\theta),$ or $\text{Binom}(1,\frac \theta n)?$

Comment: The sum is binomial($n,\theta$). The mean is that divided by $n$ (which to my knowledge has no special name).

Answer (score 1):

As Ian points out in a comment, the distribution has no particular name -- it is a Binomial$(n,\theta)$ scaled by $n$. In particular, it it not itself a Binomial, and cannot be: it takes values of the form $\frac{m}{n}$ for $0\leq m \leq n$, i.e. is not integer-valued.

Comment: Thanks !!
Finding distribution by using m.g.f is very difficult..

Comment: @SungPang Here it was not so bad, because if $X$ has moment generating function $f(t)$ then $X/n$ has moment generating function $f(t/n)$.